# Add integers to a list and find the maximum in this lit

Tags: python, list, max, palindrome

Below is some code that finds all palindrome numbers that are a product of two 3-digit numbers.

How can I modify it to create a list with all these numbers (here the x numbers printed) and get the highest number in this list?

```
for i in range(101, 1000):
    for j in range(101, 1000):
        word = str(i * j)
        if int(len(word)) == 6:
            if word[0] == word[5] and word[1] == word[4] and word[2] == word[3]:
                x=int(word)
                print(x)
```

Comment: Append the number to a list then use the `max` builtin:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: str(word) == str(word)[::-1] and you're done

Answer (score 3):

You should create an empty list beforehand and append every number. Then find the maximum using `max`:

```
palindromes = []

...your loops...
        palindromes.append(int(word))

max(palindromes)
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize an empty list and a max equal to minus infinity at starting and append x in it if it is a palindrome and update max if required.
Here is code:

```
l = []
max = float("-inf")
for i in range(101, 1000):
for j in range(101, 1000):
    word = str(i * j)
    if int(len(word)) == 6:
        if word[0] == word[5] and word[1] == word[4] and word[2] == word[3]:
            x=int(word)
            if(x>max):
                max = x
            l.append(x)
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below works great:

```
palindromes = []
for i in range(101, 1000):
for j in range(101, 1000):
    word = str(i * j)
    if int(len(word)) == 6:
        if word[0] == word[5] and word[1] == word[4] and word[2] == word[3]:
            x = int(word)
            palindromes.append(int(word))
print(max(palindromes))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, gathering all the good bits from the comments and answers, here is some code that should work:

```
palindromes = []
for i in range(101, 1000):
    for j in range(101, 1000):
        num = i * j
        word = str(num)
        if int(len(word)) == 6:
            if word == word[::-1]:
                palindromes.append(num)
print(max(palindromes))
```